# grammar, syntax and etc "is" Or "are" an essential foundation?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

I wrote these sentences:

> "I think my work is so relevant to my application because teaching English language gave me a valuable opportunity to study English closely and to have a very solid understanding of its grammar, syntax, semantics , pragmatics, phonetics and etc, which I think *is* an essential foundation for anyone who wishes to tackle the field of translation and gain professional skills".

The problem is the word *"is"* ... Is it "is" because "essential foundation" is singular or should I use "are" because I am speaking about grammar, syntax, etc.?

I think "is" is right because I do  speak about grammar, syntax and etc. as one thing or idea which is the "essential foundation".

I am not sure about this.

Comment: I would say "is", because you're saying *a very solid understanding ___ an essential foundation*.  "A very solid understanding" is singular, so it should be "is", not "are".  Don't be fooled by "syntax, semantics, pragmatics, etc." - the subject of the clause is "a very solid understanding".

Comment: Also, not "phonetics and etc," but "phonetics, etc,"

Comment: @ user3169, thank you .. a good and useful remark.

Comment: As user3169 has said, I would just like to elaborate that you don't say 'and et cetera' because 'et cetera' is a direct translation which already includes the word 'and'. Literally, it means 'and other things', or 'and so forth'. Some synonyms are: and so on and so forth, and the rest, and/or the like, and/or suchlike, and/or more of the same, and/or similar things, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is, what is "which" referring to?  What is the "essential foundation"?  It isn't the syntax, semantics, etc. which are the "essential foundation"; it's the *understanding* of the grammar, syntax, semantics, etc. which *is* an essential foundation.

Comment: Correct, By "which" I mean the understanding of grammar, syntax, etc, and its this understanding which is " the essential foundation".

Comment: So the subject is the "understanding of grammar, syntax, etc." and this is a simgular subject that needs "is" ... Correct?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.